# Download PDF of an element on the page with meteor-wkhtmltopdf

Tags: node.js, meteor, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to trigger the `wkhtmltopdf`-ization server-side of a D3-generated element rendered in the DOM, then pass that final PDF back to the client in the response.

In a nutshell, here's what I'm doing:

```
Meteor.methods({
  downloadPdf: function(data, node) {
    var filename = data.slug + "-" + data.size,
        headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".pdf"
        };
    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    var r = wkhtmltopdf(node).pipe(this.response);
    return r;
  }
});
```

And I'm calling it on the client as such:

```
Template.getPDF.events({
  'click .pdf-export-button': function(e) {
    var data = Router.current() && Router.current().data();
    if (data) {
      var node = d3.select(".pdf-export-preview").node().innerHTML;
      Meteor.call("downloadPdf", data, node, function(err, result) {
        // response goes here?
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Problem is, the above code returns a 500 error on the `Meteor.call` callback, and my terminal tells me that it's: `Exception while invoking method 'downloadPdf' TypeError: Cannot call method 'writeHead' of undefined`. Seems to indicate that the response isn't ready somehow, or something of the sort. Not really sure how to tackle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. One solution I found was to [use Iron Router to trigger the PDF download](http://blog.antobase.com/simple-meteor-wkhtmltopdf-example), but that's a problem since I need to be able to pass the rendered D3 SVG to wkhtmltopdf (along with some config stuff for the PDF).

Comment: Hm, upon further inspection it looks like passing the node as it is was causing the call stack error — so I'm doing `var node = d3.select(".pdf-export-preview").node().innerHTML;` instead. Still not sure how to pipe through the rendered PDF as a response, though.

Comment: Getting a bit closer, but still getting some weird errors. Edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Tom, did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue.  I don't want to do the piping of the rendered PDF through a server-side router call either (I want to send a template that is visible only when authenticated, which is an issue since server side router doesn't easily access Meteor.user).  Any progress?

Comment: Hey @JonnyMD, my bad, haven't actually logged into StackOverflow in a while. I ended up using the Iron Router route and passing the data to a template that the server itself renders. Example here (project is now open source):
https://github.com/globeandmail/chart-tool/blob/master/meteor/lib/routes.js#L226-L264

If you're still looking for help on this, let me know! I'd be happy to take a look.